# preg_replace - NULL result?

Tags: php, pcre

Here's a small example (download, rename to .php and execute it in your shell):

[test.txt](http://www.mediafire.com/?sharekey=fbd343f31da865cb1bee9a6e9edd9c76e04e75f6e8ebb871)

Why does `preg_replace` return NULL instead of the original string?

`\x{2192}` is the same as HTML "`&rarr;`" ("→").

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: If you copy and paste, NULL will not be returned. The problem seems to be related to special characters within the string. If I post the code, they will not be preserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation on [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace):

> Return Values
>
> preg_replace() returns an array if the
>   subject parameter is an array, or a
>   string otherwise.
>
> If matches are found, the new subject
>   will be returned, otherwise subject
>   will be returned unchanged or **NULL if
>   an error occurred.**

<s>In your pattern, I don't think the u flag is supported.</s>  WRONG

Edit: It seems like some kind of encoding issue with the subject. When I erase '147 3.2 V6 - GTA (184 kW)' and manually re-type it everything seems to work.

Edit 2: In the pattern you provided, there are 3 spaces that seem to be giving issues to the regex engine. When I convert them to decimal their value is 160 (as opposed to normal space 32). When I replace those spaces with normal ones it seems to work.

I've replaced the offending spaces with underscores below:

```
'147 3.2 V6 - GTA (184 kW)'
'147 3.2_V6 - GTA_(184_kW)'
```

Comment: "In your pattern, I don't think the u flag is supported."

Please elaborate. How can u be not supported? u simply indicates that the pattern should be treated as a UTF-8 string.

Comment: Yes, it seems PHP has problems reading the string. It was read from an Excel file using a PEAR library...

Answer (score 5):

I had an null response when my regular expression included the `u` [UTF-8 PCRE modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).  If your source text is *not* UTF and you have this modifier, you'll get a null result.

Comment: The converse is also true - if you have a UTF string, you will get a null result if you do _not_ include the `u` modifier.

Answer (score -1):

- You are using single quotes, which means the only thing that you can escape is other single quotes. To enable escape sequences (e.g. `\x32`, then use double quotes "")
- I am not a UTF8 expert, but the escape code `\x2192` is not correct either. You can do: `\x21\x92` to get both bytes into your string, but you may want to look at `utf8_encode` and `utf8_decode`
- Your source string has invalid characters in it, or something. PHP gives:
  Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 0 in test.php on line 7

Comment: Your first point is wrong - quote style have no effect here. Try this: "echo preg_replace('~\x{20AC}~u', 'EUR', '€1000');". You'll get the euro symbol replaced by EUR. Your second point is wrong, too. From php documentation: "In UTF-8 mode, "\x{...}" is allowed, where the contents of the braces is a string of hexadecimal digits. It is interpreted as a UTF-8 character whose code number is the given hexadecimal number.". Your third point - I do not get this warning on my machine, but yeah, it seems the string is malformed in PHP's view. The string was read from an Excel file using some lib...

Answer (score -3):

I believe there is also a fault in your Regex expression: `~\x{2192}~u`

Try replacing what I have and see if that works out for you: `/\x{2192}/u`

Comment: While the expression is fine, \x{2192} is meaningless in PHP, it only accepts 0-255 hex codes

Comment: @razzed: You are wrong. Please read my comment for your answer.